# class "Scanx" does not match the trust level of other classes in the same package

Tags: java, security, applet, signing

I'm attempting to use some other jar files that have functions I'd like to access.  The are public, and I have sample code I built my test app from. It appears to be signing related (ie they are signed, mine was self-signed).

When I attempt to load the applet in a webpage I am asked if I wish to block or unblock.  If I tell it to unblock I get the following error:

class "Scanx" does not match the trust level of other classes in the same package.

I've read at least a dozen different articles but they either don't apply or exceed my ability to understand at my current level of Java coding knowledge.

I'd really appreciate any thoughts on how to get past this so I can test & complete my java applet?  Code is below:

```
<html><body>
<applet id=scanx name=scanx code="Scanx.class" height="600" width="600" archive="./Scanx.jar,./ij.jar,./plugin.jar,./twain.jar"></applet>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scanit()
 {
   document.scanx.getScan();
 }
</script> 
 <input type=button onclick="scanit();">
 </body></html>
```

Here's my java code, which I compile into a jar using "jar cvf Scanx.jar Scanx.java" ...

```
package uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.applet; 
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RasterFormatException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import netscape.javascript.*;
import java.io.File;

import uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner;
import uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.ScannerListener;
import uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.ScannerDevice;
import uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.ScannerIOException;
import uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.ScannerIOMetadata;

public class xScanx extends JApplet implements ActionListener, ScannerListener{

  int     index = 0;

  String  filename;

  Scanner scanner;

  public Scanx(){
  }

  public Scanx(String title, String[] argv){    
    init();
  }

  public void init(){

    scanner=Scanner.getDevice();
    scanner.addListener(this);

//    scanner.select("TWAIN_32 Sample Source");
  }

 public void getScan()
  {
    try{
          scanner.acquire();
        }catch(ScannerIOException se){
          se.printStackTrace();
       }
  }  

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
/*
  try{
      if(evt.getSource()==acquireButton){
        scanner.acquire();
      }else if(evt.getSource()==selectButton){
        scanner.select();
      }else if(evt.getSource()==cancelButton){
        scanner.setCancel(true);
      }
    }catch(ScannerIOException se){
      se.printStackTrace();
    }
    */
  }

  public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata){

    if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)){
      BufferedImage image=metadata.getImage();
      System.out.println("Have an image now!");
      try{
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(filename+index+".jpg"));
        index++;

//        new uk.co.mmscomputing.concurrent.Semaphore(0,true).tryAcquire(2000,null);

      }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)){
      ScannerDevice device=metadata.getDevice();
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)){
      System.err.println(metadata.getStateStr());
    }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)){
      metadata.getException().printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv){
    try{
      new Scanx("Twain Applet Example [2007-11-02]", argv);
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported error message looks similar to the error when having two classes in the same package with different signatures. This has been illegal since back in the nineties. One of the differences is that the fully qualifies class name should be reported (it is about packages). It may be the case that the class is in fact in a default package, never a good idea. That would typically because the package name was added later, but an old class file that has hung around is being used.

The applet tag looks a bit wrong. `code="Scanx.class"` should have the package name in, which further suggests a stale class file. `plugin.jar` appears to be part of the PlugIN, so shouldn't be included when run in the plugin (but it will be necessary when compiling the code).

Then you say 'I compile into a jar using "jar cvf Scanx.jar Scanx.java"'. A little bit confusing. You should compile the .java file into a .class with `javac`. Then use `jar` to create the jar. The files you want should be .class not .java and should include the package name. If you look at the jar as a zip, it should have classes inside with directory paths matching package names (IIRC, `jar tf Scanx.jar` should list the files).

Comment: I was working of an example that had a typo in it and even wondered about why a system would have two compilers, one for .class and one for .jar - which was the impression I had.  Now it makes more sense.

I'm obviously deep over my head but trying to figure this out enough to use some existing code to fit a need to access a scanner via the web browser and FTP the file to the server. Steep learning curve at this point.